# Situation specific form control enable/disable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very much new to Excel developer tools (I'm using Excel 2013), and I’m just getting the hang of using/creating macros. I created a macro that if you applied a particular filter, clicking a button form control would reset all fields, or run 'Clear' under Sort & Filter. But you can still click the button despite not having applied a filter, hence getting the error message 'Run-time error '1004': ShowAllData method of worksheet class failed'.

My question is, can I disable this button in any way that when a filter is not applied, it stays inactive, but gets reactivated when a filter is applied? I hope this makes sense. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That means that you are using `.ShowAllData` method. There are multiple work arounds for this problem.

### Conditionning

```
with activesheet
    if .filtermode then
        .showalldata
    end if
end with
```

### Using a different method

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WorkSheetName").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

### Error handling (Hacky)

```
On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0
```